# Cucumber Test with Frank on Yosemite result in Segmentation Fault

Tags: objective-c, swift, cucumber, osx-yosemite, frank

I am trying to get Frank/Cucumber Framework to run on Yosemite with XCode 6.1.
I have followed the instructions on how to install and frankify a project by:

- gem install frank-cucumber
- frank setup (in the project folder)
- frank build
- frank launch

Only the last part fails with a segmentation fault:

```
LAUNCHING APP...
sh: line 1: 15828 Trace/BPT trap: 5       /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sim_launcher-0.4.13/lib/sim_launcher/../../native/ios-sim "showsdks" 2>&1
sh: line 1: 15832 Segmentation fault: 11  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sim_launcher-0.4.13/lib/sim_launcher/../../native/ios-sim "launch" "/Volumes/Project/CucuTest/Frank/frankified_build/Frankified.app" "--sdk" "--family" "iphone" "--exit" 2>&1
```

I know, that it is required to add the *accessibility* for Apps, so that the computer can be controlled by Apps. In Yosemite this has changed and I could not add /usr/bin/frank to the list, but I added the Terminal.app. Is this the problem or am I looking in the wrong place.

This is the first time I am using Frank/Cucumber.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me installing ios-sim version 3 using `brew install ios-sim` as noted [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/frank-discuss/uLSc7YDXOpY) did the trick.

Comment: This did the trick. Tested with frank-cucumber-1.2.5, Xcode 6.2 and iOS 8.2

Answer (score 0):

Just want to re-iterate this question and ask for any help. I am seeing the same issue. I am also not clear on the steps to add accessibility and anything else under Yosemite.

```
sh: line 1:  6180 Trace/BPT trap: 5       /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sim_launcher-0.4.13/lib/sim_launcher/../../native/ios-sim "showsdks" 2>&1
sh: line 1:  6184 Segmentation fault: 11  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/sim_launcher-0.4.13/lib/sim_launcher/../../native/ios-sim "launch" "/Users/ric
```

Hmmm.... Actually looks like there is an upstream Ruby error on the "Frank Setup"

```
  create  Frank/libShelleyMac.a
  create  Frank/plugins
  System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `require': cannot load such file -- xcodeproj/prebuilt/universal.x86_64-darwin14-2.0.0/xcodeproj_ext (LoadError)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:126:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/xcodeproj-0.14.1/lib/xcodeproj/ext.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
```